# Microsoft BotFramework. How get bot information (e.g. icon)

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I use microsoft bot framework .Net version (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/index.html).

I need to request bot information (icon and bot name) knowing only AppId and AppPassword.

All samples, which I saw only showed the replies to user messages.

Did anybody face with such a task?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. There isn't an API that provides information about the bot.